# Scope in Java when used in void then for loop

Tags: java, android, scope

I am struggling to get a object to correctly transfer from a void function into a for loop so that it can be iterated into a linear layout in android studios. would someone be able to outline how to do this, and the logic behind it.

```
  Backendless.Persistence.of(Tasks.class).find(
            new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Tasks>>() {

                @Override
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Tasks> tc) {
                    List<Tasks> tasks = tc.getData();
                    Log.d("ToDo", "Retrieved " + tasks.size() + " tasks");
                }

                @Override
                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault e) {
                    Log.d("ToDo", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });

    LinearLayout taskList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.taskList);

    //repeat for each task in list of tasks
    for (Tasks task :tasks) {

        //retrieve task text form object and log it
        String taskText = task.getTask();
        Log.d("ToDo", taskText);

        //create new text view and set task text
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText(taskText);

        //add text view to linear layout
        taskList.addView(textView);

    }
```

Comment: From what it looks like, `tasks` isn't even going to be computed by the time you reach your `for` loop.  The whole point of an async callback is that that callback will be called some other time in the future and you have no control over it.

Comment: Try using interface to communicate here. Define an interface in the async task class and implement it's methods (in your case handleResponse() and handleFault() ) in the class (fragment or activity).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are calling the `for` loop directly after instantiating the background process. You should call that code block once `handleResponse` method is called.

Put the `for` loop code in a new method and call that method from `handleResponse`. This way you won't have to worry about returning the `tasks` object.

Your complete code should look like this

```
Backendless.Persistence.of(Tasks.class).find(
        new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Tasks>>() {

            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Tasks> tc) {
                List<Tasks> tasks = tc.getData();
                doSomethingWithView(tasks);
                Log.d("ToDo", "Retrieved " + tasks.size() + " tasks");
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault e) {
                Log.d("ToDo", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });

private void doSomethingWithView(List<Tasks> tasks)
{
    LinearLayout taskList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.taskList);

    //repeat for each task in list of tasks
    for (Tasks task :tasks) {

        //retrieve task text form object and log it
        String taskText = task.getTask();
        Log.d("ToDo", taskText);

        //create new text view and set task text
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText(taskText);

        //add text view to linear layout
        taskList.addView(textView);

    }
}
```

Comment: i get the error "Error:(29, 33) error: List is abstract; cannot be instantiated" now. also, im trying to learn java so would you be able to describe your logic too?

Comment: Error:(44, 25) error: local variable tasks is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final.

Comment: now getting "Error:(37, 37) error: generic array creation"

Comment: I missed one important thing in your code. Updated my answer. You don't need to worry about returning any value from `handleResponse`

Answer (score 0):

As Louis Wasserman said in a comment, what you have is asynchronous.  You call `.find()` and some time later `handleResponse()` will be called with the result.  You can't get the result sooner.

The solution is to perform your processing of the result in the callback.

For example:

```
Backendless.Persistence.of(Tasks.class).find(
        new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Tasks>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Tasks> tc) {
                List<Tasks> tasks = tc.getData();
                Log.d("ToDo", "Retrieved " + tasks.size() + " tasks");

                LinearLayout taskList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.taskList);
                //repeat for each task in list of tasks
                for (Tasks task :tasks) {
                    //retrieve task text form object and log it
                    String taskText = task.getTask();
                    Log.d("ToDo", taskText);

                    //create new text view and set task text
                    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    textView.setText(taskText);

                    //add text view to linear layout
                    taskList.addView(textView);
                }
            } // handleResponse()

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault e) {
                Log.d("ToDo", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```